# Limit Microsoft Graph API permissions to a specific Sharepoint site

Tags: api

Is it possible to limit Microsoft Graph API permissions to a specific Sharepoint site?  We have developed a proof of concept that downloads and uploads files from/to Sharepoint.  However, we need to figure out how to set up the app to be limited to a specific Sharepoint site.

Answer (score 1):

There is a request for this feature on UserVoice, and it looks like it is being worked on at the moment.

https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/37796059-restrict-permissions-to-app-only-azure-ad-applicat